# Conflito de formulários

Tags: php

Tenho 2 formulários, um por ajax e o outro php normal. ambos os formulários estão funcionando, mas quando eu executo o formulário php sem ajax ele me retorna os erros do formulário php com ajax.

> PHP Com ajax

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
```

> PHP Sem ajax

```
if (isset($_POST['Btnlk'])){
```

Se o conflito não for aí eu posto todo o código.

> Código do formulário com ajax

```
<form class="form1"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div id="ressult_log_succes"></div>
    <div id="ressult_log_error"></div>

    <p>E-mail</p>
    <input type="text" name="Email_user" placeholder="Informe seu E-mail">

    <p>Senha</p>
    <input type="password" name="Senha_user" placeholder="Informe a sua senha">

    <input type="submit" id="Bot_login" name="Logar_sn" value="Logar">
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formDados = $(".form1").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url:"/complement-of-archive/ConsultaLoginUser.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:formDados,
                cache:false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(data){
                    $("#ressult_log_succes").html(data);
                },
                error:function(data){
                    $("#ressult_log_error").html(data);
                },
                dataType:"html"
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Meu formulário sem ajax

```
<form class="form2" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID_Pagina_LK_DL" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="Usuario_LK_DL" value="" placeholder="Informe seu nome">
    <input type="submit" name="Btnlk" value="1">
</form>

<?php
    require_once('SysLKDLe.php');
?>
```

> php do meu formulário sem ajax

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['Btnlk']) && $_POST['Btnlk'] == "1") {
        $LK_DL = 1;
        $ID_Pagina_LK_DL = $_POST['ID_Pagina_LK_DL'];
        $ID_Usuario_LK_DL = $_POST['Usuario_LK_DL'];

        if ($LK_DL != 1) {
        }
        else{
            $SQL_LK_DL = mysqli_query($conex,"INSERT INTO Banco_lk (LK_DL, Nome_LK_DL, IDUser_LK_DL) VALUES ('$LK_DL', '$ID_Pagina_LK_DL', '$ID_Usuario_LK_DL')");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cara, ambos os forms estão entrando no if do com ajax. Afinal, ele valida apenas se a requisição foi via POST. Ou envie um parâmetro na requisição para identificar qual form foi enviado ou mude o verbo HTTP, se possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os dois formulários estão enviando dados via `POST`, ao fazer essa verificação `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` os dois formulários entram, coloque outra condição para o `if()`, por exemplo

Formulário 1:

```
<form action="meuphp.php" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="botao_enviar" value="Cadastrar">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["botao_enviar"]) && $_POST["botao_enviar"] == "Cadastrar") {
```

Formulário 2:

```
<form action="meuphp.php" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="botao_enviar" value="Alterar">
</form>

<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["botao_enviar"]) && $_POST["botao_enviar"] == "Alterar") {
```

Vocẽ deve compara valores ou nomes diferentes nos dois formulários, pode ser o botão de envio ou campos que tenham em um formulário mas não em outro

Outra opção, é passar uma variável `op` via `GET` por exemplo:

```
<form action="meuphp.php?op=cadastrar" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="botao_enviar" value="Cadastrar">
</form>

<form action="meuphp.php?op=alterar" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="botao_enviar" value="Cadastrar">
</form>

<?php
if ($_GET["op"] == "cadastrar") {
    //...
} else if ($_GET["op"] == "alterar") {
    //...
}
```

Também pode fazer com `switch case` se prefirir

Comment: Então, eu atualizei o post. Tentei especificar o botão no php com ajax mas não me retornou nada. pq defini no meu ajax que só ia fazer a requisição do php se o "form1" fosse clicado.

Comment: coloque seu outro `<form>` e o PHP

Comment: Pronto, acabei de colocar lá.

Comment: e o PHP do `<form>` com AJAX? Ja tentou passar uma variavel op pela url e fazer um `if else` ou `switch case`?